# How do we remove ' ' from the list?

Tags: python

So I am trying to read line by line from the text file using python And I got list of lists. And I have to use the elements of the list to create dictionary. So what I did was

```
list1 = []
for line in file:
   lines = line.strip().split()
   list1.append(lines)
print(list1)
```

And what I got when I ran it is the list of lists but something different than what I wanted to get, I got something like this,

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f']
```

What I wanted to get was something like this,

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

So how do we get rid of that ' ' inside the list?
I tried to use remove method, but it did not work.

Comment: It's NOT in the list.  You are confusing the CONTENTS of the list with the REPRESENTATION of the list.  If you want it printed in a particular way, then you need to print it that way.  The list you shows contains an element `a`, which prints as `'a'`.

Comment: What is the format of your file? Is it a csv? It looks like you are getting the whole line as one string, and the split() call isn't doing anything. Try split(',') to split on the comma and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: Though it may also be worth looking into python's csv module

Comment: Note that your first code sample can be readily replaced with a list comprehension: `list1 = [line.strip().split() for line in file]`

Answer (score 2):

you just need to change the separator in the strip from the default white space to ",".
i.e you just need to add the separator argument in the strip function .

```
list1 = []
for line in file:
   lines = line.strip().split(',')
   list1.append(lines)
print(list1)
```

so if text is:

**a,b,c,d,e,f**

the strip function would take the separator as "," and create a list for it.

hence the output would be:

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

therefore finally you just need to change the separator argument of line.strip() from white spaces to comma separated list and you are done with it .

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a list with a single element. It contains a single string which is `'a,b,c,d,e,f'`.

We can double-check:

```py
data = ['a,b,c,d,e,f']
print(len(data)) # prints 1
print(data[0])   # prints 'a,b,c,d,e,f'
```

What you want is to split this string into a list:

```
row = data[0].split(',')
```

Now `row` contains what you expected `data` to be, which is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`.

In a real case you would probably fix this while reading the file, the code might look like this:

```py
list1 = []

with open('test.csv') as test_file:
    for line in test_file:
        list1.append(line.strip().split(','))

print(list1)
```

Now you would then have a list per line in your input file:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 
    ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
]
```

Comment: Is `print([data0])` supposed to be `print(data[0])`? The former doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the delimeter from '' to ','

```
list1 = []
for line in file:
   lines = line.strip().split(,)
   list1.append(lines)
print(list1)
```

you are good to go